# "Proper" place to store description about a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, metadata

Is there a proper place to store a high level description of a database?  Something along the lines of "This database is used to store XYZ for use by ABC".  It's not necessarily information one would need to query, but something that would useful for someone administering the system (i.e. me in a few months when I'm trying to remember what I was trying to accomplish a few months ago.).

This seems like something that someone would have asked before (or information that is readily findable), but none of my searching came up with anything relevant.  Most of what I found was for displaying the structure of the database itself.

Comment: Um.. in your system documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment metadata is not available for MySQL databases, but you can create a table to store some comments: (I have this table in a generic `tools` database)

```
-- Create a table to store db name and fields as need.

create table dbinfo(
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    db_name varchar(64) not null collate utf8_bin,
    db_comment varchar(255),
    unique (db_name)
) default charset utf8;
```

To fill/update `dbinfo` table with current databases:

```
insert into dbinfo (db_name)
   select SCHEMA_NAME 
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
   where SCHEMA_NAME not in (select db_name from dbinfo);
```

You will only need to maintain `dbinfo` table *until MySQL enables database comments*.